# Why a function with protected modifier can be overridden and accessible every where?

Tags: c#, oop, d, access-modifiers

I'm C# programmer new to D language. I'm a bit to confused with OOP in D programming language.

Assuming that I have the following class:

```
public class A {
   protected void foo() {
      writefln("A.foo() called.");
   }
};

public class B : A {
   public override void foo() {
      writefln("B.foo() called.");
   }
};
```

The `protected` modifier means that I can access the `.foo()` method just on inherited class,so why this **D** program compiles normally?

Here is the equivalent to **C#.NET**:

```
using System;

public class A {
   protected virtual void foo() {
      Console.WriteLine("a.foo() called.");
   }
};

public class B : A {
   public override void foo() {
      Console.WriteLine("b.foo() called.");
   }
};

public class MainClass  {
   public static void Main(string[] args) {
      A a = new A();
      B b = new B();    
      a.foo();
      b.foo();
   }
};
```

It don't compiles and given the following error message(as I expected):

> test.cs(10,30): error CS0507: `B.foo()': cannot change access
>   modifiers when overriding`protected' inherited member `A.foo()'

Can someone explain this D behavior? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you confused? C# and D are just different languages, so they do things differently. At first look, both approaches make some sense to me, so it's up to the language designers to decide which way to go.

Comment: Humm,because I had in mind that the access-modifiers of an object-oriented programming language operated in the same way.

Comment: downvotes- can explain please?

Comment: And you can do the reverse in C#, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461%28v=vs.71%29.aspx ; i.e. public/protected to private. interface I { void foo(); } class A { virtual public void foo() {} } class B : A, I { void I.foo() {} }

Comment: @Jack, they certainly don't operate the same way. For example, C++ doesn't have `internal` and C# doesn't have `friend`. Or Python, that doesn't have access modifiers at all. There is no standard on what access modifiers should an object-oriented language have. Every language is simply different.

Comment: C# has a lot of restrictions that are intended to reduce errors. "because I had in mind that the access-modifiers of an object-oriented programming language operated in the same way" -- That doesn't answer the question. Why did you have that in mind? There's no rational basis for such a belief.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's no purpose in preventing the override. The derived class could implement a trivial forwarding function that allows access. Consider:

```
public class A {
    protected virtual void foo() {
        writefln("A.foo() called.");
    }
};

public class B : A {
   protected override void foo() { // OK
       writefln("B.foo() called.");
   }
   public void call_foo() {
       foo(); // But I allowed public access anyway!
   }
};
```

Thus, even though I didn't redefine the access level of `foo`, I still allowed public access to it *and there's nothing you can do about it*. Allowing the redefinition is just simpler.

Comment: Humm,then It's `D` designer. In the `C#.NET` language, it's not possible write something like the `call_foo()` method. It given  an `error CS0122: A.foo()' is inaccessible due to its protection level.` Thanks for you reply. :)

Comment: @Jack: What, in C# you can't write a public method that calls a protected method?

Comment: No. Don't works for me,I have tested on C#-Mono and it given the above error message.

Comment: @Jack: That's because you called `A.foo()` directly in your original example. Have a look at [this](http://ideone.com/g6LXy), it seems to work fine.

Comment: @Puppy you need to add virtual keyword, check example from your link. Virtual allows you to override the method

Answer (score 8):

Because there are some great answers to the the question "why it's possible?" I think C# deserves explanation why it's NOT possible: It's about the "philosophy" of a language design, and can be boiled down to "is-a" vs "has-a" clash of ideas.

C++ is all about "has-a" thinking, some of it was passed to D and Java. B **has** method `foo` and this is most important for both the compiler and the programmer - not what B is. In C++ it's even possible to redeclare a method as private (or inherit class as private) which means that a member of A will NOT be exposed by B.

C# is hardcore about "is-a" concept. Therefore because here B actually **is** A, everything in B must be just like in A. Neither compiler nor the programmer have to worry about changes, because no changes are possible. B always is a perfect drop-in replacement for A.

The "is-a" philosophy forbids C# program from publicising previously protected member, even though it's trivial to do it via a public wrapper. It makes little sense and is just a small inconvenience here - but it's a big deal in keeping the language philosophy consistent.

Answer (score 7):

D's behavior in this matches Java's behavior. A derived class can give its function an access level which is less restrictive than the one on the function in the base class but not one which is more restrictive. So, a `protected` function can be overridden as either `protected` or `public`, but it can't be overridden as `private`, and a `public` function can only be overridden as `public`.

I have no idea why C# would restrict `protected` such that you couldn't override it with a `public` function. As someone who's programmed a great deal in C++, D, and Java but very little in C#, C#'s choice here makes very little sense to me. C++, D, and Java all allow it.